# No module named "Skimage" ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, scikit-image

I have tried untinstalling "scikit-image" and installing again but keep getting the same thing?

```
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity as ssim
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skimage'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
python -m pip install -U scikit-image
```

Answer (score 1):

try to install skimage;

```bash
sudo apt-get install python3-skimage
```

or

```bash
pip install scikit-image
```